# Bash: how to suppress newlines?

Tags: bash, scripting, file

I'm trying to extract fields from a pipe-delimited file and provide them as arguments to an external program in a loop. The file contains lines like this:

```
value1|value2
value3|value4
```

So I came up with:

```
 while read line;

    do echo -n "${line}" | awk -F '|' '{print $1}';
       echo -n " something ";
       echo -n "${line}" | awk -F '|' '{print $2}';
       echo " somethingelse";

 done < <(cat $FILE)
```

I want to see the following output:

```
value1 something value2 somethingelse
value3 something value4 somethingelse
```

But instead I'm getting:

```
value1 
 something value2
 somethingelse
value3
 something value4
 somethingelse
```

Perhaps I shouldn't be using echo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `awk` supports `printf`, I would use that instead. Even though `echo -n` doesn't add a newline, `awk {print}` does. The `printf` variant will not put the newline at the end like `print` does:

```
echo -n "${line}" | awk -F '|' '{printf "%s", $1}'
```

Here's your version hex-dumped, note the `\n` at the end when you pass it through `awk`:

```
pax> echo -n "hello|goodbye" | od -xcb
0000000    6568    6c6c    7c6f    6f67    646f    7962    0065
          h   e   l   l   o   |   g   o   o   d   b   y   e
        150 145 154 154 157 174 147 157 157 144 142 171 145
0000015

pax> echo -n "hello|goodbye" | awk -F '|' '{print $1}' | od -xcb
0000000    6568    6c6c    0a6f
          h   e   l   l   o  \n
        150 145 154 154 157 012
```

and here's the `printf` version:

```
pax> echo -n "hello|goodbye" | awk -F '|' '{printf "%s", $1}' | od -xcb
0000000    6568    6c6c    006f
          h   e   l   l   o
        150 145 154 154 157
```

And here it is, running on your real file (named FILE in this example to ease my testing):

```
pax> while read line;
     do
         echo -n "${line}" | awk -F '|' '{printf "%s", $1}';
         echo -n " something ";
         echo -n "${line}" | awk -F '|' '{printf "%s", $2}';
         echo " somethingelse";
     done < <(cat FILE)

value1 something value2 somethingelse
value3 something value4 somethingelse
```

Comment: Bingo! Thanks for the detailed explanation as well!

Answer (score 1):

@OP, there's no need to use `cat`. Also in the while loop, you can set IFS (input field separator) to pipe `|`, and there's no need to use external commands for every line parsed. It's inefficient. Here's how to do it with just the shell

```
while IFS="|" read -r a b
do
   echo "$a something $b somethingelse" # use echo without -n
done <"file"
```

you can also use `printf` which is more portable than `echo`.

output

```
$ ./shell.sh
value1 something value2 somethingelse
value3 something value4 somethingelse
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed` for this:

```
$ cat test
value1|value2
value3|value4
$ sed 's/|/ something /; s/$/ somethingelse/' test
value1 something value2 somethingelse
value3 something value4 somethingelse
$
```

---

Update:
For your original question, you can remove newlines with `tr -d '\012'`, e.g.

```
cat ${FILE} | while read line
do
        echo "${line}" | awk -F '|' '{print $1}' | tr -d '\012'
        echo -n " something "
        echo "${line}" | awk -F '|' '{print $2}' | tr -d '\012'
        echo " somethingelse"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while read line;
    do
            echo  "${line}" | sed  s/'|'/' something '/| sed  s/$/' somethingelse'/;
 done < file1
```